# iPad add tabBar with in detail view

Tags: ipad, tabbar

I want to show 3 different screens depending on the option user selects

[image: screen where i have 3 options]

They are 1. Type Prescription 2.Scribble Prescription 3. Prescription Form

How can i switch views for those 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITabBarControllers like SplitViewControllers were intended to only be the Root View Controller and hence you cannot nest a TabBarController in another view, but you can however nest a UITabBar in a view.

I added the Tabbar to the details view at the bottom, a Navigation bar at the top and then a placeholder view between them. All in Interface Builder!, You will want to switch everything on with the autosize on the Placeholder view.

Next, Implement the UITabBarDelegate, you will need:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
```

from that you can use item.tag which if you give each item a unique tag in Interface Builder will let you know which tab the user clicked. I setup defined values for mine:

```
#define VIEW_TAB_A 0
#define VIEW_TAB_B 1
#define VIEW_TAB_C 2
```

Then you will then want to...

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
[self switchToView:item];
```

}

```
- (void) switchToView : (UITabBarItem*) item {

    if( currentViewController != nil ) {
        [currentViewController viewWillDisappear:NO];
        [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];               
    }

switch(item.tag) {
    case VIEW_TAB_A:
        currentViewController = self.viewA;
        break;
    case SCAN_VIEW_TAB_B:
        currentViewController = self.viewB;
        break;
    case PROMOTIONS_VIEW_TAB_C:
        currentViewController = self.viewC;
        break;
}

UIView *aView = currentViewController.view; 

aView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
aView.frame = placeholderView.frame;

[currentViewController viewWillAppear:NO];

[self.view insertSubview:aView aboveSubview:placeholderView];
if( currentViewController != nil ) {
    [currentViewController viewDidDisappear:NO];
}
[currentViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

}
These are my notes that i learned from a similar question, search harder next time

Comment: Thanks for the input, do you have any links which asking for same question?